# Program in mips matrix

Tags: assembly, mips

Perform an MIPS program that given a 3x3 matrix stored in memory
perform the multiplication of its diagonal.

```
             1  2  3
             4  5  6
             7  8  9
```

Presented by the product screen res = 1x5x9 = 45

I need some idea of ​​how to do it? please

Comment: By, er, taking the elements on the diagonal and multiplying them together? It's not clear what your problem is here.

Comment: By taking the first element on the diagonal and multiplying it by the second item on the diagonal, then multiplying the result by the third item on the diagonal, and so on until you run out of items.

Comment: I dont know how to read from the keyboard and then save it in the matrix?

Comment: Shouldn't that be part of your course material? In any case, you can find [syscall references](http://students.cse.tamu.edu/wanglei/csce350/reference/syscalls.html) for SPIM and MARS on the internet.

Comment: you are right but this program is for a research project and do not understand how to do it in any way thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have programming knowledge,in any programming language the algorithm to resolve a diagonal matrix is basically same: Loop to read matrix ("Loop For")- Get elements by same x.y position ("matrix[i][j] -> i = j") - Multiplicate.

You should find resources about example codes in MIPS, to see how work it. The input and output work by the famous "system calls". That link is a good summary.

Pd: ¿Español, no?